# Highlight the 2nd item in a breadcrumb list

Tags: html, css

I have a breadcrumb list with multiple items listed horizontally. 
In certain cases, I want to highlight the 2nd list item. The list items are generated dynamically. Is there a way to do so?

For example, if the output looks like this, I want to highlight "Blue Area" section using `background-color: lightgray`.

`Main Dashboard > Blue Area > Admin Settings > Set Color`

Here is the HTML code snippet:

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb" data-bind="foreach: breadcrumb" style="float:left;display:inline-block">
        <li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: text"></a></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? Tip: look into the `:nth-child` CSS selector…

Comment: As an alternative since this is dynamic behavior you'll want js for the case of having more than 2 children example `if(number of children >= 2){...} else{...}`, the `...` represents whatever logic you want to use to determine the class application (number of elements, user behavior, page behavior, etc)

Comment: @Callat - I don't see how this would require JS. As the answer below states, you can target the second list-item with `.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2)`. If you want to only do that when there are more than two items, you can simply append a `:not` selector: `.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2):not(:last-child)` - will only target the second item if the second item is not the last one, meaning there will be more than two items.

Comment: @ChrisBoon OP said `In certain cases, I want to highlight the 2nd list item. The list items are generated dynamically.` What if these cases are more involved than just changing a single color? And what other logic goes into this cases? That's why I recommended JS and left it as a comment rather than mapping out a whole answer.

Comment: @Callat. Fair enough - the question is ambiguous enough that it's not clear what the 'certain cases' are. It could just be 'if the list is on 'page X' which may have a class name on the body for example. Looking closer at the code sample it looks like it's written in knockout.js, so it may be a ternary operator and the 'style' or 'css' binding would be most appropriate if the logic goes beyond 'if there are two or more items'. Without more info as to what is needed it seemed that suggesting js was overkill, but maybe our comments will get the original poster to clarify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul.breadcrumb {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
ul.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "/\00a0";
    background: #eee;
}

/* To highlight word by chnaging color */
ul.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a {
color: yellow;
}

/* To highlight word by chnaging background color */
ul.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) {
background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Summer 15</a></li>
  <li>Italy</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know that you will always highlight the 2nd list item in the ordered list, then you could just write a css rule to do so:

```
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

`nth-child()` is 1 indexed.

If it is not always the 2nd list item in the ordered list, then you could add a class when you are creating the list items dynamically.